# oAuth2 sign in issues in ionic mobile application

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, ionic3, google-oauth, cross-platform

I am working on ionic 3 application and I want to implement sign in with google functionality here. I have created ABC project in google developer console. I have configured consent screen for OAuth2. When I am trying to create credentials with OAuth2 client Id, I am not able to understand whether to select **Web Application** as a **application type** or anything else since I am using Ionic and which is a cross platform application development platform.

[image]

Please let me know if Ionic is a web application.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely choose a web application. The application type is needed to allow for some flows (e.g. a TV application might have the device flow enabled, while a web application might not). Apart from that I think that Google is also collecting this data for statistic reason - how many of the registered apps are for iOS, how many are for Android, etc. Though there might be different features/requirements depending on the chosen type of the app.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michal. I have one more doubt. I am trying to install ionic-native google plus plugin which requires me to add app bundle id in command itself. But I have two different bundle ids for android and ios. How can I deal with this situation, any idea??

Comment: That sounds like a tough one. Unfortunately I don't have any ideas how to solve it. Maybe you should somehow have two different installations of the plugin?